# How can I send the out of the last pipe to two different commands?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

So, I have text file with a a bunch of numbers, one number per line to be specific, so I do:-
`cat filename.txt|sort -n|head -1` to get the top number and I can do `cat filename.txt|sort -n|tail -1` to get the bottom number.
Just to be sure is there a way to send `cat filename.txt|sort -n|` and its output to two different commands in one line and have the out put (the highest number and the lowest number next to each other)

Answer (score 2):

You can do interesting things with `tee` and process substitutions, but the order of the output may not be stable (due to timing of processes)

```sh
sort -n filename.txt | tee >(tail -1 >/dev/tty) | head -1
```

In this case, I'd use sed to print the first and last line:

```sh
sort -n filename.txt | sed -n '1p; $p'
```

As @chepner suggests

```sh
... | sed -n '1p; $p' | paste - -     # tab separated
```

or

```sh
... | awk 'NR == 1 {first = $0} END {print first, $0}'   # space separated
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to to make it so that the two outputs are on the same line and next to each other?

Comment: Pipe it through `paste - -`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful command `tee` syntax `tee second.txt` will output to second.txt

You can combine that with bash executive pipes eg `tee >(wc)`,

So you can do 2 or more commands by eg  `tee >(wc) | head`